# Why is my local Laravel Homestead returning site can't be reached

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have installed a Laravel project on my local Windows machine and have run the following commands

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

On the vagrant prompt that appears, I enter the commend below:

```
cd code
```

On my browser, I type in homestead.test. Instead of the Laravel welcome page opening, I get the error, *This site can’t be reached. homestead.test’s server IP address could not be found*.

On the vagrant prompt, I entered the command below to check on the configuration.

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

The configuration is active, i.e not commented out

127.0.0.1 homestead.test

Comment: can you show your Homestead.yaml?

Comment: The IP reads 192.168.10.10. I'll try to change the etc/hosts config. Thanks :-)

Comment: i guess you need to configure that on your Windows machine `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: Make sure that you are changing the hosts file of your host OS and not inside the vagrant VM. You could also test the site by going to the IP in your browser.